# How do you find out about upcoming conferences in your research area?

Tags: conference

Once in a while I find out that an interesting conference in my research area has taken place, but I did not hear about it. Usually when I find out about upcoming conferences it is when a friend, colleague or collaborator lets me know. But sometimes interesting conferences are organized by people outside my immediate research circle, so I don't hear about them until it is too late. Is there a way to keep tabs on what conferences are going on in a particular research area? My area is math/mathematical physics, but I imagine this is a question that academics of all fields might be interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is short list of tips:

- Ask your supervisor. They should know a lot of upcoming conferences.
- Learn about the "yearly cycle" in your field. In which month in which conference, when are deadlines usually…
- Subscribe to mailing lists in your field. Follow some societies or active people in your field on social media.
- Do regular searches on the internet (e.g. every two or three months.

On top of that: You will get familiar with more conferences over time and you'll build a network where you'll get information also about smaller meetings.

Answer (score 3):

At my university, there is an internal website (and staff!) devoted to precisely this issue. The site shows the conference topic, conference website link, dates of the event and submission dates for papers. The great thing about the list is that it is curated, so one does not have to wade through an overwhelming number of pages  about conferences that are either scams, or not well respected.

I know that my university is not alone, at least in my part of the world ... so it would be worth your while to inquire at the office of the VP Research at your own university about something similar.

You might also have a look at [this page](https://guides.library.uwa.edu.au/keepingresearchcurrent/conferences) which is a list of links and guides to various conferences. It's not as well curated as my university's internal list, but it's a good start.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of any such offer. Is your internal website attempting to cover all research areas? It almost seems wasteful, as I'd often expect there to be at most one faculty member at a given university to be potentially interested in a given conference.

Answer (score 2):

For me, a common way to find out about conferences and workshops in my area stems from being registered to a few mailing lists. These often also cover job advertisements for my field.

In my experience, most events are either part of an annual conference series or by invitation only. For the latter, you'll obviously find out if you are invited (by receiving the invitation), and don't really need to know it otherwise. For the former, once you've learned about the conference series once, you can actively check for the next years edition. It's common that people are aware of stuff like "The deadline for conference X is usually in January", which then informs a more specific Google search.